# Network Map with full detail and hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, ip

I wrote a piece of code to run from the first IP address to the last and retrieve the MAC and Hostname of devices in my network.

But, **i do not know how to get the hierachy of then**. Information like what router is the device conected (via Cable of WiFi also). And some routers are not managed (they don't have IP - they are just "switchs").

First, i didn't think it was possible, since a "tracert" on the CMD does not show then, but when i call the "Network Complete Map" on Windows Control Panel, they get all the information i need - so there is a way. See the image below:

[image]

The "switchs" circled in red have no IP, the "TL-xxxx" are routers with DHCP turned of. The "gateway" is a server that has the DHCP and provides connection to the internet.

Thus far, i wrote the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Network
{
    [Serializable] public sealed class Map
    {
        private bool mMARKED = true;
        private long mDB = 0L;
        private string mIP = string.Empty;
        private string mMAC = string.Empty;
        private string mBRAND = string.Empty;
        private string mNAME = string.Empty;
        public bool Save { get { return this.mMARKED; } set { this.mMARKED = value; } }
        public long DBId { get { return this.mDB; } set { this.mDB = value; } }
        public string IP { get { return this.mIP; } set { this.mIP = value; } }
        public string MAC { get { return this.mMAC; } set { this.mMAC = value; } }
        public string BRAND { get { return this.mBRAND; } set { this.mBRAND = value; } }
        public string NAME { get { return this.mNAME; } set { this.mNAME = value; } }
    }

    [Serializable] public sealed class Scanner
    {
        public const string WebOUIFile = "http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt";
        public const string LocalOUIFileName = "oui.txt";
        private const long MaxOUIAge = (TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * 90L);
        internal Dictionary<string, string> OUIList;
        private List<Map> mDevices = new List<Map>(50);
        public List<Map> Devices { get { return this.mDevices; } }
        public static Scanner Scan;
        public Thread Worker;
        public bool AutoSave { get; set; }
        private string Node;
        private byte mInitial;
        public static string UploadPath { get; set; }
        public byte Initial { get { return this.mInitial; } set { this.mInitial = value; } }
        public byte Current { get; private set; }
        public byte Limit { get; set; }
        public bool Working { get; private set; }
        public string Errors;
        public string Message { get; private set; }
        public bool UpdatingOUI { get; private set; }

        public void Interrupt()
        {
            this.Working = false;
            if (this.Worker != null)
            {
                this.Worker.Abort();
                this.Worker = null;
            }
            this.Node = string.Empty;
            this.Initial = 0;
            this.Current = 0;
            this.Limit = 0;
            this.Working = false;
        }

        public void ToDestroy()
        {
            this.Interrupt();
            this.Errors = string.Empty;
            this.Message = string.Empty;
        }

        public void Stop(bool immediate) { if (immediate) { this.Interrupt(); } }

        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] private static extern int SendARP(int DestIP, int SrcIP, out long pMacAddr, ref int PhyAddrLen);
        public void ToBegin() { }
        public void Stop() { this.Stop(true); }

        private static int IPToInt(string Expression)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] IPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Expression).GetAddressBytes();
                return (Convert.ToInt32(IPAddress[3]) << 24) | (Convert.ToInt32(IPAddress[2]) << 16) | (Convert.ToInt32(IPAddress[1]) << 8) | Convert.ToInt32(IPAddress[0]);
            } catch { return 0; }
        }

        private Map GetBasics(string IPString)
        {
            int res = Scanner.IPToInt(IPString);
            if (res > 0)
            {
                long mem = 0L;
                int PhyAddrLen = 6;
                if (Scanner.SendARP(res, 0, out mem, ref PhyAddrLen) == 0)
                {
                    Map dev = new Map();
                    byte[] macbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(mem);
                    dev.IP = IPString;
                    string Tmp = BitConverter.ToString(macbytes, 0, 3);
                    if (this.OUIList != null && this.OUIList.ContainsKey(Tmp)) { dev.BRAND = this.OUIList[Tmp]; }
                    dev.MAC = Tmp + "-" + BitConverter.ToString(macbytes, 3, 3);
                    try { dev.NAME = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPString).HostName.ToLower(); } catch { dev.NAME = "unknow"; }
                    return dev;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static void GetNode(ref string IP, ref string Node, ref byte Device)
        {
            string[] NodeComp = IP.Split('.');
            Node = NodeComp[0] + "." + NodeComp[1] + "." + NodeComp[2] + ".";
            Device = Convert.ToByte(NodeComp[3]);
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> DonwloadOUTFile(bool ForceUpdate = true)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> List = null;
            try
            {
                string Aux = Scanner.UploadPath;
                if (Aux == null) { Aux = string.Empty; }
                else if (Aux != string.Empty)
                {
                    string Tmp = Aux + "~" + Scanner.LocalOUIFileName;
                    Aux += Scanner.LocalOUIFileName;
                    bool FileExists = File.Exists(Aux);
                    if (FileExists && ((DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - (new FileInfo(Aux)).CreationTimeUtc.Ticks) > Scanner.MaxOUIAge))
                    {
                        File.Delete(Aux);
                        ForceUpdate = true;
                    }
                    string Aux2 = string.Empty;
                    if (ForceUpdate)
                    {
                        List = new Dictionary<string, string>(25000);
                        using (WebClient Downloader = new WebClient()) { Downloader.DownloadFile(Scanner.WebOUIFile, Tmp); }
                        using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Tmp))
                        using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(Aux))
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                Aux = Reader.ReadLine();
                                if (Aux.ToLower().Contains("(hex)"))
                                {
                                    Aux2 = Aux.Substring(0, 8).ToUpper();
                                    Aux = Aux.Substring(Aux.LastIndexOf('\t') + 1);
                                    if (!List.ContainsKey(Aux2))
                                    {
                                        List.Add(Aux2, Aux);
                                        Writer.WriteLine(Aux2 + "\t" + Aux);
                                    }
                                }
                            } while (Reader.Peek() >= 0);
                            Reader.Close();
                            Writer.Close();
                        }
                        try { File.Delete(Tmp); } catch { /* NOTHING */ }
                    }
                    else if (FileExists)
                    {
                        List = new Dictionary<string, string>(25000);
                        using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Aux))
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                Aux = Reader.ReadLine();
                                if (Aux != null && Aux.Length > 9)
                                {
                                    Aux2 = Aux.Substring(0, 8);
                                    if (!List.ContainsKey(Aux2)) { List.Add(Aux2, Aux.Substring(9)); }
                                }
                            } while (Reader.Peek() >= 0);
                            Reader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (List != null) { List.Clear(); }
                List = null;
            }
            return List;
        }

        private void ReadScaner()
        {
            this.UpdatingOUI = true;
            try { this.OUIList = Scanner.DonwloadOUTFile(ForceUpdate: false); } catch { /* NOTHING */ }
            this.UpdatingOUI = false;
            if (this.OUIList == null || this.OUIList.Count == 0) { this.Errors += "\nErrorOUIFileDownload"; }
            Map Dev = null;
            this.Current = this.Initial;
            if (this.Limit < this.Initial)
            {
                Dev = this.GetBasics(this.Node + this.Initial.ToString());
                if (Dev != null) { this.Devices.Add(Dev); }
            }
            else
            {
                bool ToAdd = true;
                while (this.Current <= this.Limit)
                {
                    Dev = this.GetBasics(this.Node + this.Current.ToString());
                    this.Current += 1;
                    if (Dev != null)
                    {
                        ToAdd = true;
                        foreach (Map iDev in this.Devices)
                        {
                            if (iDev.MAC == Dev.MAC)
                            {
                                ToAdd = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ToAdd) { this.Devices.Add(Dev); }
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Message = "Finished!";
            this.Interrupt();
        }

        public void GetRange(string IPInitial, byte Limit, bool AutoSave = true)
        {
            if (!this.Working)
            {
                this.AutoSave = AutoSave;
                this.Working = true;
                Scanner.GetNode(ref IPInitial, ref this.Node, ref this.mInitial);
                this.Limit = Limit;
                this.Worker = new Thread(this.ReadScaner);
                this.Worker.IsBackground = true;
                this.ToBegin();
                this.Worker.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void GetRange(bool AutoSave, string IPInitial, byte Limit)
        {
            if (Scanner.Scan == null)
            {
                Scanner.Scan = new Scanner();
                Scanner.Scan.GetRange(IPInitial, Limit, AutoSave: AutoSave);
            }
        }

        ~Scanner()
        {
            if (this.OUIList != null)
            {
                this.OUIList.Clear();
                this.OUIList = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do i make that code able to get the hierarchy like windows does?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes. That windows screen shows the network map and relations, my map code list ip/mac only. how do i make my C# code able to relate devices, as the windows control panel, network complete map does?